# Why PowerShell.exe There is no way to dot source a script?

Tags: powershell, dot-source

The help document says that the script will be executed in 'dot-sourced' mode, but it doesn't. why?

I read the full text of the help document and couldn't find the reason, so I came for help.

```
PS> PowerShell.exe -File '.\dot-source-test.ps1'
PS> $theValue
PS> . '.\dot-source-test.ps1'
PS> $theValue
theValue
PS>
```

The content of 'dot-source-test.ps1' is `$theValue = 'theValue'`.

> If the value of File is a file path, **the script runs in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the functions and variables that the script creates are available in the current session.**

[about_PowerShell_exe - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 6):

To prevent conceptual confusion:

In order to **dot-source a script**, i.e. execute it *directly in the caller's scope* (as opposed to a *child scope*, which is the default), so that the script's variables, function definitions, ... are seen by the caller:

- **In the *current* PowerShell session**, just use `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), *directly*:

  ```
  # Dot-source in the caller's scope.
  # When executed at the prompt in an interactive PowerShell session,
  # the script's definitions become globally available.
  . '.\dot-source-test.ps1'
  ```
- **Via `powershell.exe`, the [Windows PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)**<sup>[1]</sup>:

  - Note: Whatever dot-sourcing you perform this way is limited to the *child process* in which `powershell.exe` runs and *its* PowerShell session; it has no impact on the *caller's* session.
  - **Dot-sourcing via the CLI makes sense only in two scenarios**:

    - Scenario A: You're passing commands via the (possibly positionally implied) `-Command` (`-c`) parameter that relies on definitions that must first be dot-sourced from a script file, and you want the session to exit automatically when the commands have finished executing.
    - Scenario B: You're entering a (possibly nested) *interactive* PowerShell session into which you want to dot-source (pre-load) definitions from a script file; as any interactive session, you will need to exit it manually, typically with `exit`.

**Scenario A: Pre-load definitions, execute commands that rely on them, then exit:**

The following starts a (new) PowerShell session as follows:

- Script file `.\dot-source-test.ps1` is dot-sourced, which defines variable `$theValue` in the caller's (here: the global) scope.
- The value of `$theValue` is output.
- The new session is automatically exited on completing the commands.

```
PS> powershell -c '. .\dot-source-test.ps1; $theValue'
theValue
```

**Scenario B: Enter a (new) interactive session with pre-loaded definitions:**

Simply add the `-noexit` switch in order to enter an *interactive session* in which script file `.\dot-source-test.ps1` has been dot-sourced:

```
powershell -noexit -c '. .\dot-source-test.ps1'
# You're now  in a (new) interactive session in which $theValue is defined,
# and which you must eventually exit manually.
```

Note:

- If neither `-File` nor a command (via explicit or implied `-Command` / `-c`) are specified, `-noexit` is *implied*.
  Because `-c` is needed here for dot-sourcing, `-noexit` *must* be specified to keep the session open.
- **While using `-File` for dot-sourcing instead - `powershell -noexit -File '.\dot-source-test.ps1'` - works too, I suggest avoiding it for conceptual reasons**:

  - While **it is *technically* true that a script passed to `-File` is dot-sourced in the new session**, that is (a) unexpected, given that scripts executed from *inside* a session are *not* (they run in a *child scope*) and (b) by far the most typical use case for `-File` is to execute a given script *and then exit* - in which case the aspect of dot-sourcing is *irrelevant*.
  - As such, **it is better to think of this behavior as an *implementation detail***, and it is unfortunate that the [CLI help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) mentions it so prominently - causing the confusion that prompted this question.

---

<sup>[1] The same applies analogously to the **PowerShell [Core] 7+** CLI, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), except that it defaults to `-File` rather than `-Command`.</sup>

Comment: Excellent answer! It solved a problem I was dealing with trying to load a script function into the current command shell by dot sourcing. Was .\Do-Something.ps1 and the function would not be loaded. In 7 if you are in the same folder it tells you to use .\ for local which is correct but misleading.  Do this:   .  ".\Do-Something.ps1"

Answer (score 2):

It's about the way the path to the file is passed through the command line. See the below example when used in Command Prompt. (test.ps1 contains the line `$theValue = 'theValue'`)

[image: CMD window example]

Without using the "-File" toggle, it's treated differently, as an argument to be passed to the PowerShell process being triggered.

Seeing the same thing when calling in PowerShell.

[image: PowerShell Window sample]

The specific part you reference is under the " -File" toggle, which needs to be used.

> If the value of File is "-", the command text is read from standard input. Running powershell -File - without redirected standard input starts a regular session. This is the same as not specifying the File parameter at all.

> If the value of File is a file path, the script runs in the local scope ("dot-sourced"), so that the functions and variables that the script creates are available in the current session.

(source: [Microsoft Docs > About PowerShell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1#-file----filepath-args))

Comment: But your explanation seems to be wrong.`PowerShell.exe '.\dot-source-test.ps1'` and `PowerShell.exe -File '.\dot-source-test.ps1'` are equivalent,Both of them are not working properly.The real key is parameter `-noexit`.